# Contiki 6lbr router produces not enough memory error

Tags: contiki

When running 6lbr in router mode on a Openmote I get the error `ERROR: NODE: Not enough memory to create node [node ipv6 addr]`.
I can not find the error in any source file and therefore it is hard to see why it might happen!
Has anyone seen this error before or know how to solve it?

I run the router with RDC: contikimac_driver and MAC: csma_driver. The branch on the cetic/6lbr git rep is develop.

The info on the routers webpage tells me:

```
Memory
Flash : 86990 (16 %)
  Code : 84781
  Initialized data : 2209

RAM : 29429 (89 %).
```

and the routing table with my 4 motes:

```
Routes
[del] aaaa::212:4b00:60d:9b57/128 via fe80::212:4b00:60d:9ac3 7668 s
[del] aaaa::212:4b00:60d:9b59/128 via fe80::212:4b00:60d:9ac3 7659 s
[del] aaaa::212:4b00:60d:9abb/128 via fe80::212:4b00:60d:9abb 7600 s
[del] aaaa::212:4b00:60d:9ac3/128 via fe80::212:4b00:60d:9ac3 7586 s
```

Comment: Solved this with a patch from the author!